# Passing DTO to front end when the data passed is different from the db table (Java)

Tags: database, dto

What is the - or is there a - convention for passing DTO data to the front end, when the front end doesn't need all the data in the DTO, or needs it to be organised differently?

For example, I might have a DTO for students, their courses and their course scores. On the other hand, my front end is only presenting the student data and, in this contrived example, their average scores across all courses.

So when I get the student data, I also get from the db the avg for each student's course scores. This isn't really part of the "student" data, so it doesn't quite belong there.

OTOH it really isn't part of the course data either. What is the standard for this - to make a new DTO to hold the Student DTO and the avg score? To pass a tuple? Or Something Else?

I'm writing in Java, but I suppose there might be a language-agnostic convention? Or not?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no standard on this matter. Back to the old days when the network was a bottleneck, best practice was to minimize amount of data to transfer. Nowadays, no one seems concerned about amount to transfer of data anymore. Nevertheless, you still should try to pass only the information you need, excluding data which can be trivially calculated on the client side. The DTO could be completely different to you domain objects. 
In your particular case, your DTO could be 'student data' and include student info and average score. As you writing Java, try to avoid tuples as it will become hard to maintain once your project grows to a decent size.